# How can I enable footer in dompdf?

Tags: php, footer, dompdf

Please, focus on the footer part. I want to display a kind of pagination in footer. This is what I've tried:

```
   <?php
    //error_reporting(0);
    ini_set("gd.jpeg_ignore_warning", 1);
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . "dompdf");
    require_once('dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();

    $html ='<script type="text/php">';
        if ( isset($pdf) ) {
            $footer = $pdf->open_object();
            $font = Font_Metrics::get_font("helvetica", "bold");

            $pdf->page_text(72, 18, "Header: {PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}", $font, 6, array(0,0,0));
            $pdf->close_object();
            $pdf->add_object($footer, "1");
        }
    $html = $html.'</script><html>TEST<br><br> ';

    $html .='</html>';
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    $output = $dompdf->output();
    file_put_contents("pdf_generated/file.pdf", $output);
    header("Location: http://acros.netlogiq.info/pdf_generated/file.pdf");
  ?>
```

The result is :nothing displayed in the footer? What can I do?

Comment: thx for the edit, but can you provide me an answer ? or could you help with this ? thx

Comment: Have you enabled PHP? Look at `DOMPDF_ENABLE_PHP` in the dompdf_custom_config.inc.php file, or set it manually after instantiating dompdf by calling `set_option()`, e.g. `$dompdf->set_option('enable_php',true);`

Comment: Also, when using the `page_text()` method you don't need to open and close an object. Page text is handled outside the normal bounds of page generation.